What is the gameplay benefit of engaging with portal storms?
In Cataclysm: Dark Days Ahead, there is an extreme weather event called a "Portal Storm". During portal storms, a bunch of crazy, nonsensical enemies spawn in and reality fractures, and some weird effects happen around you, which can potentially be fatal to your character. In my own games I've seen portal storm spawns of (mild spoilers)

 impossible shapes, memories, and persons.

What you're meant to do if you want to survive the storm is hunker down indoors, ideally in an enclosed structure with no windows or open doors, and just wait it out, ignoring anything that tries to beckon you out like false screams or hallucinations. Supposedly portal storms also get worse over time, but I can't verify that as I always just hide out and wait for them to be over.
My question is, as of the current stable release (0.H), is there any reward or benefit for engaging with portal storms? Do you get something for being brave enough to stay out during a storm, or are you just meant to hide and wait it out? I've seen some people on forums talking about "portal storm dungeons" or some reward that you can get, but I've never found anything like that in my own games and I can't find any documentation on what portal storm rewards or "portal storm dungeons" are, beyond people vaguely hinting on Reddit. I also had a strange occurrence during my last portal storm event where coordinates appeared in my character's mission log, so I assume if I were to go there I would find a "portal storm dungeon"?

In the storm is a "dungeon" that appears at the coordinates you get.
According to ambrux on this Reddit post,

Once you are no longer able to continue [through the dungeon], or have the amount of resets needed for your reward, you leave through the gate you came in from.
Less than 5 resets - A buff: +4 Dex for 2 days
Less than 10 resets - An item: Escape stone
10 or more resets - Friendly shadow that infinitely respawns
The buff is okay. It's not worth much, but it is easy to get.
The [escape stone] item is a panic button that takes you to nowhere which is a cavity in space that looks like the dungeon but is otherwise safe. You leave automatically after some time has passed.
The last reward is a bit weird and I don't fully understand everything about it. It spawns a tainted shadow that follows you like the friendly manhacks do, and runs off to fight hostile things it can see. If it loses sight of you, it will wonder around aimlessly. It is mediocre in battle and dies to most things pretty fast. However, it seems that whenever it dies, it just comes back somewhere else. Not sure if there is a limit on this respawning, but its a hassle to take the shadow anywhere due to its AI being unable to understand Z-levels. It also makes noise when moving, keeping you awake at night and making your npcs go "what was that" endlessly. And you can't kill it for good. I locked mine in a one-tile closet so I can sleep. Thankfully it can't open doors.


How's this relate to portal storms?

This answers my question, thanks! I looked at some more forum posts and it seems like if you follow the coordinates that pop up in your mission log during said storms, you reach a randomly spawned dungeon and can do "runs" through it to get these rewards before the storm dissipates.

@Malady Forgot to add that - see my edit.
